# Set dirty dot in mac window using Qt

Tags: c++, macos, qt

[screen shot http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/2338/200911231633.png](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/2338/200911231633.png)

Is there a way to set the dirty dot (as shown in the screenshot) using Qt 4.5/4.6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [QWidget::setModified()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qwidget.html#windowModified-prop)